# Two script completing the same task, which is the best way?

Tags: php, sql, array

I have the following two methods of completing the same task, however I'd like to know ***which is the preferred method and WHY?*** Or if there are any suggestions to complete the task in an even better, cleaner way.

***The task***

Find part 1 of `$string` in the example `$string = '1/2/3/4';` so the first part would be '1'.

Match that value to the corresponding 'id' from entries in the database, then return the 'filename' that corresponds to the 'id'.

Then loop again until each part of the initial string has a corresponding value.

The 'filename' values are each then output to a string delimited by a '/'.

EG. `filename1/filename2/filename3/filename4`

***Option 1***

```
$string = '1/2/3/4';

$change = str_replace('/',',',$string);

$result = $connection->query("SELECT id, filename FROM pages WHERE id IN($change) ORDER BY FIELD($change)");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $match[] = $row;
}

foreach ($match as $array) {
    echo $array['filename'].'/';
}
```

**UPDATE**
This works fine if there are more than one parts to the string eg. '1/2/3/4' but I get the following error if just '1' is used.

`Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\pages\test2.php on line 22`

**OR**

***Option 2***

```
$string = '1/2/3/4';

$split = explode('/', $string);

$split = array_flip($split);

$result = $connection->query("SELECT id, filename FROM pages");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $new_array[$row['id']] = $row['filename'];
}

$matched = array_intersect_key($new_array, $split);

$join = implode('/', $matched); // join $matched as string.

echo $join;
```

Comment: is the string always guaranteed to be delimited by /

Comment: Yes, unless there is only one value then it will just be the value.

Comment: if $string is 6/10/33/44 - then we would be matching 6 into the DB - then lets say we get two files out of that then you want to echo the two file name (assuming file name is codereview and stackexchange) it would be codereview/stackexchange ?

Comment: 6 would correspond to one filename. eg. 'codereview', 10 would be another filename eg. 'stackexchange'. so 6/10 = codereview/stackexchange

Comment: ahhh ok -gotcha.

Comment: essentially, each number is an index for the filename. each unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = '1/2/3/4';

$change = str_replace('/',',',$string);

$result = $connection->query("SELECT id, filename FROM pages WHERE id IN($change) ORDER BY FIELD(id,$change)");

$new_string = "";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $new_string .= $row['filename']."/";
}

$new_string = substr($new_string,0,-1);

echo $new_string;
```

Less looping - the `match[] = $row` was unnecessary IMO because you want a string back only...so you concatenate the file name with a `/` delimiter and then the last slash is removed with `sub_str`.

**Updated the fixes including single query match.**

Comment: Just tested and only pulls the last part of the string,   ie. '4' in the example. also sub_str should be substr.

Comment: i apologize - fixed it - forgot the dot in $new_string .= $row

Comment: i'll give it a test now

Comment: this doesn't (as with my option 1) if there is only one part to the string, eg. '1' instead of '1/2/3' etc. I get... `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\pages\test2.php on line 22`

Comment: It will be due to `query("SELECT id, filename FROM pages WHERE id IN($change) ORDER BY FIELD($change)")` expecting more than one value in the brackets.

Comment: check my edit. it should work for singular return now also.